# Java order of OR comparison

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

does the following snippet throw NPE when argument is null?

```
public void doSomething(String string) {
    if (string.trim().equals("") || string==null) {
    [...]
    }
}
```

I've found this in someone else's code (someone else who should be more experienced than me). Since I've been facing difficulties with this code, I want to ask if the comparison should be inverted or the Java compiler is someway smart enough to swap the operands. I don't have direct control over this code, nor this throws me NPE because of many catch blocks.

Thank you

Comment: See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.24 - `evaluates its right-hand operand only if the value of its left-hand operand is false`

Comment: And what is we use them (`&&` and `||`) in combination? Is there an order of execution? Or is it still left-to-right evaluation?

Comment: Why don't you try it by yourself? Literally 5 lines of code and you know the answer.

Comment: The parameter is named str, but the variables are named string.  Is this correct?

Comment: @walkingTarget: I just corrected the question after @Martijn Courteaux corrected my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. That snippet of code will throw a `NullPointerException` when `string` is `null`. Changing it to the following is advisable:

```
public void doSomething(String string) {
    if (string==null || string.trim().equals("")) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I felt free to change the parameter name to `string` :D

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: Thanks. I didn't quite spot that the argument variable name was different than the variable name in the `if` block. I had just cut/pasted it from the question. Looks like it was wrong in the question too but I just corrected it there.

Answer (score 4):

It will throw a `NullPointerException` because if `string` is null and you try to trim a `null` it will throw the exception. Try putting the null check before you try to `trim().`

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, that looks dodgy to me.  It should almost certainly be the other way round.  Java logical operators (like in C and C++) have a "short-circuit" facility, whereby the left-hand operand is evaluated first, and then the right-hand operand is only evaluated if needed.

*[Note: Couldn't you have just tried running this to find out whether it throws an exception?]*

Comment: I can't debug in the code I just looked at. Think about it, you even got some more rep :)

Comment: @djechelon: You could simply have copy-and-pasted this snippet into a small test program...!

Answer (score 2):

binary operators of equal precedence are always evaluated from left to right, apart from assignment (in just about every language I can think of)  This is important in this case, because `||` is a short cut operator.  If the result is know i.e. the first expression is true, the second expression will not be evaluated.  So the correct way to use `||` and `&&` to check for null is like the following.

```
if(text == null || text.method())
```

or

```
if(text != null && text.method2())
```

The order is this way as we read left to right (and top to bottom) in English. c.f. In Japanese you read from top to bottom then right to left.

Comment: This is not a precedence/associativity issue.  In C/C++/Java (and some others), the logical operators have a "short-circuit" facility.

Comment: For me the important issue is that the left expression is evaluated before the right expression.  The OP's code would work with a short cut if the right were evaluated first.

Comment: Actually, short-circuiting means that the second operand is NOT evaluated when the first is sufficient. This is essential to avoid splitting null-check and pattern check because if null-check passes, then the other operand is not evaluated and doesn't go NPE

Comment: short circuiting only means that not all the sub-expressions are evaluated when the result is known.  In logical programming languages, ANY sub-expression if known can mean the other expressions are not evaluated.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, but in Java (and C, etc.), there is a specific point in the standard that states that the left-hand operand is *always* evaluated, and the right-hand operand is only evaluated *if necessary*.  That is the key point here...

Comment: @Oli, Which is why that is what I said in my answer, or at least I thought I did. ;)

Comment: @Peter: Indeed, but your answer missed out the key point, which is the short-circuit facility!  So `a() && b()` is fundamentally different to `a() + b()`, for instance.

Comment: Also, it's not true that operators of equal precedence always have left-to-right associativity... (http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/)

Comment: @Oli, it lists `?:` as `right to left` even though this is a short circuit operator and the condition is always evaluated first.

Comment: @Peter: Associativity dictates the order that multiple instances of the same precedence are bound, not the order that the arguments of one instance of an operator are evaluated.  In the case of `?:`, it means something like `a ? b : c ? d : e` is equivalent to `a ? b : (c ? d : e)`, and not `(a ? b : c) ? d : e`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, every sensible IDE will complain about this code, because the right half can never be evaluated.

```
 if (string.trim().equals("") || string==null) {
```

if the string is null, the left part throws a NPE, so the right part never gets evaluated

Comment: The right half can be evaluated.  It will just never be evaluated to `true`.

Comment: @Atreys I meant `if (the string is null){ the left part throws a NPE, so the right part never gets evaluated }` :-)

Comment: @atreys: no matter the value of right expression, if I get NPE there is no need to evaluate anything more and that's a pain in the ... :)

Comment: This entire answer seems incorrect. I can't think of any Java IDE that I've used that would complain about this, just because the variable -might- be null, and therefore -might- throw a NullPointerException and -might- mean that the right hand side can't be evaluated. And, if you think about it, doing so would be totally ridiculous.

Comment: Eclipse definitely prints no warning in both the null and not-null case.   It only complains about uninitialized variables, not null ones.

Comment: @smackfu true, I get no warnings with plain eclipse either. However I always have the PMD plugin turned on and that certainly gives me a warning: "Misplaced Null Check: if the variable is null, there'll be a NullPointerException". One might argue that PMD is required to turn Eclipse into a "sensible IDE" :-)

Answer (score 2):

try that with `if(!"".equals(someString))` which enables to avoid an explicit null-check

Comment: That doesn't behave the same (where is the trim?), and isn't an answer to the question...

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth , @Asaph String that contains WhiteSpace Char(s) isn't isEmpty for me in all of cases